# Refreshing parent window from child window without losing parent data

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have one page with one datatable and some other input data in parent form. If I click on a record of datatable, I will open a popup, enter the data and save the data. After saving the data in popup I will submit the parent to refresh the datatable and close the popup. For this I am using the following code.

```
window.opener.document.forms[0].submit();
window.close();
```

With the above child window is closing but parent is not refresing for updated databale.
In parent I am using

```
<t:saveState value="#{parentform.dlist}"/>
```

If I use

```
window.opener.location.href="parent.jsf?id="+id;
```

the problem will be solved, but I am losing the input data in parent whis was entered before openeing the popup.
Please suggest me any solution ASAP? The solution should work for both the scenarios.
Thanks